# Consulta MySQL excluindo LINHAS vazias

Tags: mysql

tenho que fazer uma consulta (que será levada a uma aplicação PHP) na tabela abaixo. Gostaria de realizar a consulta de modo que não fossem selecionadas as linhas que não contenham preços (ou seja que são null) nas colunas 'gnbr' até a 'sprd'. Não quero excluir as linhas que estão em branco (pois se amanha precisar cadastrar preços nelas, precisaria digitar novamente o cod, prod, fab, qtd e carac.) apenas quero fazer a consulta de modo que o result set a ser enviado pro php nao receba essas linhas. a quantidade de linhas é variável (sempre haverá cadastro de coisas novas) portanto não posso fazer 'WHERE cod = xxxx;' por exemplo. alguem pode dar um norte, pelo menos??
grato.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Faça gnbr is not null e assim sucessivamente

Comment: No caso acima quais linhas seriam mostradas? coloque um exemplo ou pelo menos fale o cod de tal por exemplo iria aparecer!?

Comment: Pense também em rever o modelo , nome de colunas ininteligéveis , estrutura sem normalização , um novo tipo de preço demanda uma nova coluna.

Comment: as linhas mostradas seriam: cod 7100,7210,7211 e 7212. As linhas ignoradas seriam: cod 7101, 7300,71000 e 72000. Os nomes das colunas são abreviações de supermercados da região. @VirgilioNovic

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde.
Você precisa indicar a condição no WHERE. Pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE gnbr IS NOT NULL AND sprd IS NOT NULL.
```

Você precisa adicionar manualmente cada elemento com "AND {nome_do_campo} IS NOT NULL".

Answer (score 1):

Se quiser verificar se a linha tem pelo menos um `NULL`, você pode somar todas as colunas numéricas em questão e excluir as linhas em que essa soma for `NULL`:

```
WHERE (gnbr + vnse + ... + sprd) IS NOT NULL
```

Ou:

```
WHERE NOT ISNULL(gnbr + vnse + ... + sprd)
```

Não sei sobre a eficiência dessas variações. A soma das colunas certamente tem um "peso" sobre a consulta, sugiro analisar um `EXPLAIN` dela.

Se quiser eliminar só as linhas onde todas as colunas forem `NULL`, pode usar isto:

```
WHERE COALESCE(gnbr, vnse, ... , sprd) IS NOT NULL
```

O `COALESCE` funciona estabelecendo uma cadeia de *fallbacks*. O resultado só será `NULL` se todas as colunas estiverem nulas.